# How to Extract Information with web scraping using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract Information from the website  .
If you go to this website, there will be list of items in left side, if you click one of the option,
in right side you will get table which has Name & Code. I needto create a dataframe which has Code and Name Column which is scraped from the website?
In some options it doesn't give Name & Code Table, that should be skipped.

Output Dataframe Columns :

```
Name   Code
```

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scraper__, __scrape__, __scraped__) not scrapping

Comment: Whatever "the website" is, you need to write code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to get all ids, names and codes from this site:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://taxonomy.nucc.org/"
page_url = "https://taxonomy.nucc.org/Default/GetContentByItemId/"

html_doc = requests.get(url).text

treenodes = re.search(r"var treenodes = (\[.*\]);", html_doc)
treenodes = json.loads(treenodes.group(1))

all_data = []

for n in treenodes:
    data = requests.get(page_url + str(n["id"])).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.get("PartialViewHtml", ""), "html.parser")
    code = soup.select_one('label[for="Code"]')
    code = code.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True) if code else None

    print(n["id"], n["name"], code)

    all_data.append(
        {
            "id": n["id"],
            "name": n["name"],
            "code": code,
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
...
82   1863                            Attendant Care Provider  3747A0650X
83   1864                            Personal Care Attendant  3747P1801X
84   1866                 Advanced Practice Dental Therapist  125K00000X
85   1867                                   Dental Assistant  126800000X
86   1868                                   Dental Hygienist  124Q00000X
87   1869                       Dental Laboratory Technician  126900000X
88   1870                                   Dental Therapist  125J00000X
89   1871                                            Dentist  122300000X
90   1884                                          Denturist  122400000X
91   1885                                    Oral Medicinist  125Q00000X
92   1872                               Dental Public Health  1223D0001X
93   1873                           Dentist Anesthesiologist  1223D0004X
94   1874                                        Endodontics  1223E0200X
95   1875                                   General Practice  1223G0001X
96   1876                   Oral and Maxillofacial Pathology  1223P0106X
97   1877                   Oral and Maxillofacial Radiology  1223X0008X
98   1878                     Oral and Maxillofacial Surgery  1223S0112X
99   1879                                     Orofacial Pain  1223X2210X
100  1880           Orthodontics and Dentofacial Orthopedics  1223X0400X
...
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]